# Is this set computable?

Tags: computability

Let be $B$ a Busy Beaver function and set $W=\{\langle M \rangle :\text{$M$ stops in less than $B(10^{1000})$ steps on an empty tape}\}$. Is this set computable?

---

I'm not sure how to approach this question. I suspect that this set is computable and have tried to see if it is finite, but haven't reached anything.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $W$. What is $M$?

Comment: Hi @YuvalFilmus is a turing machine, thanks!

Comment: Let me phrase this differently. When does an integer $n$ belong to the set $W$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus when $n$ is a number of a turing machine (is a similar numeration of a Gödel numeration) and tha Turing machine with number $n$ stop with input the empty tape and stop in less $B(10^{1000})$ steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is computable. Just run the input machine on the empty input for $B(10^{1000})$ steps. Note that $B(10^{1000})$ is just a constant which can be hardcoded into your code.